# Getting the region of an Amazon bucket using webservice

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to get the location of my bucket by calling Amazons web service.
I'm using the following url : -

```
https://mybucketname.amazonaws.com/location?
X-Amz-Expires=86400&
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=<Access Key>%2F20170524%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&
X-Amz-Date=20170524T162340Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&
X-Amz-Signature=f800dce1258a3d43d19929a37c98f3dedf5e5164e807ccf70ef396be5a1e7cf0
```

Unfortunately it comes back with an error: -

> Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-2'

That's probably because I have used `us-east-1` in the `X-Amz-Credential` part of the request. It is a requirement that region be added to `X-Amz-Credential`.
The trouble is I don't know what region I should be using because this is the very thing I'm trying to find out.

Is there a better way to get the region?

Comment: I *believe* `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name?location` will work as expected if signed with a `us-east-1` credential, regardless of the bucket's location.  Try that?

Comment: Yes this used to be the case, unfortunately if you try doing it that way now you just get a 'PermanentRedirect' message

Comment: Verified, it still works that way.  I've just re-tested it.  Signing with `X-Amz-Credential=...us-east-1` requesting the location of a bucket that I know is in `us-east-2`, I get the correct response: `<LocationConstraint xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">us-east-2</LocationConstraint>`.  But you *have* to use a path-style URL `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name-goes-here`.  If you do `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` then that won't work, and has probably never worked with a region mismatch using Sig V4.  I've marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, i just get the permanent redirect error.
This is what I'm using : -

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/{mybucket}/location?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={mykey}%2F20170530%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170530T085530Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=dd63c4baa5acc91288fd9208f96ee3380d3cc4c6e7c41478b014ee9e947b5867`

Comment: The error is subtle but it's in your URL.  `https://s3.amazonaws.com/{mybucket}/location?X-Amz-...`. Location is a subresource, so it goes after `?`, not before.  You want `https://s3.amazonaws.com/{mybucket}?location&X-Amz-...`.  [Confirmation bias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) must have kicked in, and I completely overlooked this in your original question.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks Michael, I finally got it working. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

Below [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command gives the info. Given the URL you wrote, seems like you are writing your own code from scratch to query AWS. Any reason for not using AWS SDK?

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket my-bucket

{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: The code is being used in an SQL server assembly. So as I understand it the AWS SDK can't be referenced from there. I'm quite new to this so I don't know all the ins and outs of it